# ¿Cómo obtener todos los componentes presentes en una página en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Necesito poder mapear todos los componentes que se encuentran cargados en una página como podría ser el HOME, para luego accederlos dinámicamente a través del DOM.

Suponga la siguiente estructura

```
<WrapperContext>
  <ComponentA />
  <ComponentB />
</WrapperContext>
```

He leído de la documentación oficial `ReactDOM`, `FindDOMNode` pero no me ha servido o no he sabido implementarlo correctamente.

Estructura del proyecto:
Folders:

- Components
- Layouts
- Pages
- Context

El objetivo es cambiar el texto de esos componentes a través de un ContextProvider que envolverá a todos los componentes.

Edición 06/10/2022

Encontré un fragmento de código que pasado dentro un componente wrapper donde debería de ir la etiqueta `{children}` crea y pasa dinámicamente props a todos los elementos que este Wrapper envuelva.

```
<>
{React.Children.map(children, child => 
(React.cloneElement(child, {style: 
{...child.props.style, background: "red!important"}})))}
</>
```

Si abstraigo este código de la siguiente manera:

`console.log(React.Children.map(children, child =>   child))`

Vemos lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se han creado las `:key` props, pero el ref sigue siendo null.

Faltaría poder añadir una `ref` dinámicamente a cada hijo de este context con `createRef` del hook `useRef`.

Comment: En la documentacion de FindeDOMNode dice ``In most cases, you can attach a ref to the DOM node and avoid using findDOMNode at all.``, probaste con refs?

Comment: Hola Agustín, gracias- Es una app que ya tengo bastante avanzada para ese approach tendría que haber previsto de poner refs en cada componente que creé! Pero no lo hice ya que la idea de adjuntar los textos a los componentes dinámicamente surgió después. En la extensión de REACT-DEVELOPER-TOOLS para chrome la pestaña "components" me muestra el árbol completo de toda mi app, supuse que si esa extensión accede a todo el árbol de componentes el método por el cual lo hace debe venir en la librería de REACT. Sería genial que alguien supiera hacerlo como lo hace la extensión